# Error on update translation

Tags: updates, installation, translation, localhost, local-installation

I installed a fresh version of WordPress in my current language (pt_BR) on localhost (WAMP). After log in, WordPress told me that exist an translation update. I clicked to update and the following message appeared:

```
Atualizando traduções de WordPress (pt_BR)…
O pacote não pôde ser instalado. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Translation

```
Upgrading Translations of WordPress (pt_BR)…
The Package : can not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

I try to update language files manually , but the update indicator keep popping up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718745/3691686

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_zip
```

Comment: Be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer to mark your question as resolved.